# Issue loading resources using mod_jk with httpd and tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I have a tomcat application. I am also using apache server and connected it to tomcat using mod_jk. Here I used rewrite module to change my url and but when my website is running, page resources (css, js) are not loading correctly.

My tomcat application name `Mahmudul`. I want to make the url  `www.mahmudul.com`, so I configured httpd.conf file. here is my configurtion.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.mahmudul.com

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Mahmudul/$1 [l,PT]
 JkMount /* tomcat1
</VirtualHost>
```

If I configured the URL to load from `www.mahmudul.com/Mahmudul`, not everything works fine because then resources location is `/assets/css/styles/`. But I changed the above configuration to make the URL `www.mahmudul.com`. but now the location of resources `/Mahmudul/assets/css/styles/` and resources are not loading. Also when clicking any links such as "contact", link shows "/Mahmudul/contact" and also session id is attached with the links. I want to omit `/Mahmudul`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Here I didn't have to rewrite URL. I used the same virtual host configuration but without RewriteEngine. I just needed to configure tomcat server.xml and added a new host configuration. Here is configuration-

```
<Host name="mahmudul.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.mahmudul.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="Mahmudul-1.0-SNAPSHOT" debug="0" privileged="true" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
</Host>
```

Here is my worker.properties

```
worker.list=tomcat1
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
```

And my apache httpd.conf virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mahmudul.com
        ServerAlias www.mahmudul.com
        JkMount /* tomcat1
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it helps. Thank you.